# Checkout remote branch in a failsafe way, throwing local changes away?

Tags: git, git-checkout, git-reset

Common recommendations to reset your working copy (`master` branch) to the state of the upstream branch seem to be:

```
git checkout master
git fetch
git reset --hard origin/master
```

and

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard
git pull
```

Or with detaching the HEAD:

```
git checkout origin/master
git reset --hard
git pull origin master
```

The problem I have with these is that they are not fail-safe. The working copy could be in a state which results in a checkout error:

> error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten
>   by checkout:
>
> ...
>
> Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches. Aborting

What seems to do the trick is the following:

```
git fetch
git checkout --force origin/master -B master
```

The checkout is forced, getting rid of local changes. The remote branch is checked out, overwriting a possibly existing local branch `master` and not detaching the HEAD. `origin/master` should refer to the latest remote HEAD because `git fetch` is run before the checkout.

My question: are there additional Git corner cases which could prevent these commands from failing? Some weird working copy state, like in the middle of a merge, with untracked files becoming tracked or vice versa, ignored files being staged, submodule related things or something along these lines?

What commands would be equivalent to deleting the entire working copy and cloning the repository again? (I don't want to actually re-clone because the repository in question is huge.)

Comment: Doing a hard reset before pulling should make the specific error message you highlighted go away.  Hard reset will wipe out both your working directly and stage.

Comment: Yes, but it may require another reset if I'm not mistaken: pull could result in a merge conflict. There are multiple options to bypass that, but I think my proposed two commands would be more efficient to achieve the same result.

Comment: Yes, but following with a hard checkout/pull should work.

Comment: `git reset --hard HEAD; git clean -dfx`

Comment: I tried `git pull --hard` before but it does not exist unfortunately  Anyway, I don't see any reason why I should do a hard reset before a forced checkout/pull, if the latter implicitly resets the branch anyway. @EncryptedWatermelon Under what exact circumstances would cleaning be required? Ignored files are ignored, so they shouldn't affect what you push back to the remote branch unless you force-stage an ignored file - but that should be taken care of by the forced checkout?

Comment: The checkout does apparently not set the remote branch as upstream automatically, so that is something to consider - the local branch may have no or a different remote counterpart set. `git branch --set-upstream-to origin/master` or `git push --set-upstream origin master` or `git push origin HEAD:master` should solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A force-checkout will overwrite untracked files in the working directory if they are tracked in the to-be checked-out branch, but it will *not* remove untracked files that are *not* part of the checkout.

Clean checkout the way I recommend it:

**First clean up** the working directory:

E.g. use **one of these** approaches:

- stash changes and untracked files away for possible later use with
  `git stash save -u 'some message'`.
  If you ever need them again, you can restore those changes with
  `git stash apply stash{0}`
  If you want to inspect the stashed changes you can do so with
  `git stash show -p stash@{0}`
  and if you want to inspect the stashed untracked files with
  `git show stash@{0}^3`.
  Note: The stash number (`0`) may change if you save more stashes after this.
  Consult `git stash list` if in doubt which number to use.
- stash changes and untracked files **and** ignored files by first double-checking which ones there are using `git status --ignored` and then using `git stash save --all 'some message'`.
- delete changes and untracked changed for good with `git reset --hard HEAD; git clean -f -d`. Make sure you that you actually want to do this as you cannot undo this.
- delete changes untracked files **and** ignored files by first double-checking which ones there are using `git status --ignored` and then using `git clean -f -d -x`. Make sure you that you actually want to do this as you cannot undo this. Usually this should *not* be necessary to avoid checkout collisions.

***After your cleanup*** of your working directory you should be able to **checkout** whichever branch you want without collisions.

---

> (I don't want to actually re-clone because the repository in question is huge.)

Not sure if you're aware, so just in case that the bandwith is the problem here:

You can clone repositories locally. So instead of re-cloning e.g. from github, you could instead do a local `git clone ./repo repo_new` and the adjust the origin in the new repo e.g. with `git remote set-url https://mygitsvr/user/repo`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Your remark about force-checkouts only overwriting _some_ untracked files is a good point that I hadn't thought about. A hard reset and clean up before checkout seems justified and removes the need for `--force` in the checkout. However, `origin/master -B master` is still required. The particular working copy is for CI automation, so no need for stashing changes. Local cloning sounds interesting, but the source of truth is the remote repo and I rather care about CPU and I/O performance than network bandwidth (resolving deltas + file checkout > download time).

Comment: I see. Then a forced checkout followed by a `git clean -f -d` (with `-x` if desired) is probably the fastest approach.